# Adding 'Getters' and 'Setters' for the sake of unit testing?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I am currently working with some pretty iffy code. The code itself is not legacy, but the framework it uses is legacy and is pretty bad.

I want to start writing some junit tests for a class (for a change!) but in order to do so effectively I would need to add some getters and setters.

I need the setters so I can check the state of the private variables in the class (a kind of state machine design pattern going on here) and I need the getters to mock what the private variables in some methods are.

Would you guys say its bad, good or simply acceptable to add getters and setters to a class for the sake of being able to write unit tests?

Comment: You could always use reflection to retrieve the fields off of the class without using getters and setters.

Comment: One of the problems with a reflection-based solution is that it stops you from using your IDE's "find usages" or "workspace references" features to find where a particular member is being used.  It also breaks the IDE's "rename" feature.  If you find yourself using reflection in your tests, you're setting yourself up for maintenance difficulties in the future.  You're also basically doing the wrong thing - if you're testing the contract of a class, you should never need reflection; and if you're not testing the contract of a class, then what possible use is your test?

Comment: This class implements (or at least tries to implement) the state machine design pattern. I need to test that when method X is run when boolean Y is set to false, the state of variable Z is set to a certain value, and if variable Y is set to true, variable Z is set to something else. Please let me know if I am talking nonsense :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would avoid it.  Generally speaking, you should structure things as best you can to avoid needing to test private variables and stick with the interactions that the rest of the application will be exposed to.  This is typically public methods/properties and protected methods by using fakes/doubles.

The purpose of the unit tests are to verify how the object under test is interacted with, not necessarily it's implementation details.  Basically, with input x, I should get output/effect y.  If you get hung up on testing exactly how x produces y, you run the risk of making your classes inflexible to change.  Every refactor of your class is likely to break your tests, even if the output and end result is the same.

Comment: This is the best answer.  If your test is setting or checking private variables, then you're testing the wrong thing.  Test that your class obeys its contract - that it does what it's supposed to.  You never need to touch private variables in order to do that.

Comment: What if I am testing a class that implements the state machine design pattern and is built using a pretty bad framework that is not very testable.

The flow of the class and a lot of the decisions it makes is based on the state of private variables, therefore checking what the state of variables are seems to equate to checking that input X results in effect/output Y.

Correct me if I am wrong please!

Comment: If an application or other portion of the code using the class would never look directly at private variables (because it can't) then there is no reason to unit test them directly as you're getting to focused in doing so.  If, as in your example, you need to read that state, then the getters/setters should be there to begin with, as it's reasonable to assume that some other class may need to look at the private variables.

Black Box classes (information hiding) is a fundamental tenant of OOP, and simply put, you don't need to test the hidden information, that's why it's hidden.

Comment: Hi Brad, cheers for the input. As I said I am working with a pretty bad/old framework. No other classes ever look at the variables or even the state of this class - the only interaction with the outside world this class has is when its "startFlow" method is called, and the rest happens "internally" within the class. There are public methods and private variables...and thats pretty much the majorirty of it. Is it wrong/bad that I want to test that the flow of my class is working as intended?

Comment: Isn't that testing the flow of someone elses class?  If it's truly procedural to that degree where it's a "fire and forget" approach to running it, it's going to be inherently hard to test.  I would argue that if you can add getters/setters to it to peak at it's data, possibly exposing future problems, then you should be able to refactor it into something that is more amicable for testing.

Comment: To be clear, what you are suggesting and your intended use is really harmless.  BUT adding pathways that wouldn't exist otherwise just for unit testing is code smell and adds risk into the project when someone ends up modifying or depending on things that they shouldn't have because they didn't know better.

Comment: Agreed that it is code smell - having getters at the end of a class for the sake of unit testing. But then again...isn't having zero unit tests for a huge multi-million pound project even more smelly? Also I don't see how having getters and setters could have any negative effects as other classes can't/won't actually call it with the way this framework is currently implemented.

Comment: However, after I invoke the public member function which does lots of things. How can I be confident to assert that it's functioning well internally ? Maybe its return value is right, but internally something's wrong. So in this situation, just assert return value is not enough ?

Answer (score 5):

Adding code to production code solely for unit tests is something which I try to avoid.

An alternative for your case would be to retrieve the values via reflection, as it is possible to access even private members.

```
Field field = object.getClass().getDeclaredField("member");
field.setAccessible(true);
Object value = field.get(object);
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot now and let you know how it goes :) Sounds like a nice solution.

Comment: Making the fields public fixed the exception - it seems it cant access the fields if they are private..

Comment: Oh sorry, my example contained the wrong method. `getDeclaredField()` is the method I was thinking of.

Comment: Wowza this worked nice and easy.

I doubt there is any way to do the same with setting private variables....im 99% sure there isn't but i'll ask just in case!

Comment: I haven't used it yet, but there is also a `Field.set(Object,Object)` method, which should do what you want. You can do anything with Reflection, as long as there is no SecurityManager ;)

Comment: This information has been extremely useful. It will help me out a lot right now and I'm sure it will proove useful in the future too. Many thanks!

Comment: Don't do this.  In the past, I have been badly burnt having to maintain code that uses this technique.  Unit tests should never need reflection anyway.

Comment: I actually agree that a clean design is a lot preferrable to using this technique. But I do think it has its uses for testing legacy code, if it is used sparingly.

Comment: You can give Spring's [ReflectionTestUtils](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html) a try.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer having all dependencies passed into the constructor, but assuming that would be too difficult to add to your existing system, just ensure the getters and setters are package private and clearly label them (annotation or javadoc) that they are visible purely for testing. Even better if you could add some static analysis tools to ensure the getters and setters are not called from production code only from test.

Comment: Unfortunately adding dependencies into the constructor is not possible with the current pattern/framework that is used (that's how bad it is!).

This seems like a practical and reasonable solution.